# What's the potential danger of overriding a private function to public?

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

I just find out that overriding a private function to a public one from base object is allowed in C++ since Visual Studio produces 0 warning. Is there any potential danger to doing that?

If there isn't, what's the difference between declaring a virtual function in private, protected and public in a base object?

Comment: You cannot override a `private` method in Java. I've removed mentions of that in your question.

Comment: If someone use it polymorphically he can't call the private function, even if it is public in the derived class... btw, doing this makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Rahn `overriding a private function to a public one from base object is allowed in C++ since Visual Studio produces 0 warning`  be careful making assumptions like this. Because it produced 0 warning doesn't mean it's allowed in C++, it means it's allowed in Visual Studio. And even then, may produce a warning if the warning level is turned up (I don't know for sure). Anyway, the point is that even though one compiler is fine with it, doesn't mean another would be. The C++ standard is the real authority here.

Answer (score 2):

> what's the difference between declaring a virtual function in
>   private, protected and public in a base object?

The difference is that a `private` virtual function can be called only from a base class. This can be useful if the function is not a part of an external class interface, and is only used by base class. So that users call (some other) base class' member, and that member calls the virtual function. For example:

```
class Base {
    virtual void stage1()=0;  // derived classes override this
    virtual void stage2()=0;
  public:
    void run() { stage1(); stage2(); } // users call this
};
```

---

Moreover, there is a point of view that you should not make your virtual functions `public` at all, because the fact that they are virtual is internals of the class and its subclasses, and the users should not be aware of that. It is rarely that the same function must be overridden and callable from external code. This allows the base class to control which (virtual) functions can be called from which (non-virtual) public method, making maiteinance easier.

See more details in [this article by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm):

> ...each [public] virtual
>   function is doing two jobs: It's specifying interface because it's
>   public...; and it's specifying implementation detail,
>   namely the internally customizable behavior... That a public virtual
>   function inherently has two significantly different jobs is a sign
>   that it's not separating concerns well and that we should consider a
>   different approach. What if we want to separate the specification of
>   interface from the specification of the implementation's customizable
>   behavior?
>
> ...
>
> In summary, prefer to make base class virtual functions private (or
>   protected if you really must). This separates the concerns of
>   interface and implementation, which stabilizes interfaces and makes
>   implementation decisions easier to change and refactor later.

However, I am not qualified to say whether this is really widely used...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any potential danger to doing that?

I don't think so, because you are still very limited:

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){ Base::foo(); }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.foo(); //error
    Base * d2 = new Derived2();
    d2->foo(); //error
}
```

So at best you will be able to call the overloaded function (if it doesn't call the function from the base class from itself), but the function of the base class will still have the same visibility, and will be inaccessible.

Comment: `virtual void foo(){ Base::foo(); }` Wait... Will this actually compile? There should be an error here, not only in `main()`, since `Base::foo()` isn't accessible to child classes...

Comment: Yes, of course, the error will point to that line as well as the one in main, that's the point. Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

When changing access visibility by overriding in derived class, base class visibility doesn't change:

So with:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
protected:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() override {};
};
```

Then

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;

d.foo(); // valid
b.foo(); // invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there isn't, what's the difference between declaring a virtual function in private, protected and public in a base object?

It depends on how you access the function. The type of the object/pointer you use determines whether you can access the function.

```
class Base
{
   public:

      virtual void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   private:

      virtual void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
   Derived* dptr = new Derived;
   Base* bptr = dptr;

   dptr->foo();  // Can't use it. Derived::foo is private
   bptr->foo();  // Can use it. Base::foo is public.
}
```

Compiler message, using g++ 4.9.3.

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:12:20: error: ‘virtual void Derived::foo()’ is private
       virtual void foo() {}
                    ^
socc.cc:20:14: error: within this context
    dptr->foo();  // Can't use it. Derived::foo is private
```

Answer (score 0):

A virtual function is a customization point for derived class implementations. If it is private then it's purely an implementation detail. Making it more accessible in a derived class then exposes an implementation detail, with all that that entails. In particular client code can come to depend on that detail so that the implementation can't be easily changed. It can also be easier for client tode to call in incorrect ways, than the originally intended interface, and it can yield results that are only valid in certain contexts, so that it's more brittle than the original interface.